# How to delete object from list in JSON using SpringBoot and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In my project, I am using Spring Boot and MongoDB.

I would like to remove object from list in JSON by `objectId`:

I have a profile object in the database that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61c05611a8237a39811ec3c0"),
    "runningStyle" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61c05616a8237a39811ec3c1"),
            "name" : "name1",
            "priority" : "priority1",
            "average" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61c05616a8237a39811ec3c2"),
            "name" : "name2",
            "priority" : "priority2",
            "average" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61c05616a8237a39811ec3c3"),
            "name" : "name3",
            "priority" : "priority3",
            "average" : "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to remove `object` by its `ID` in list `runningStyle` in Profile object.

This is what I have tried in code:

**RunningController.java**

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/delete/{runningStyleId}")
public void deleteRunningStyle(@PathVariable String runningStyleId){
   playingStyleService.deletePlayingStyle(playingStyleId);
}
```

**RunningServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
public void deletePlayingStyle(String playingStyleId) {
        profile.ifPresent(up -> savedPlayingStyle.ifPresent(sps -> {
           
            up.getPlayingStyle().stream().filter(am -> am.getId().equals(playingStyleId))
                    .findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(ps -> profileRepository.deleteById(ps.getId()));
          
            playingStyleRepository.deleteById(playingStyleId);
        }));
}
```

With this code, I don't have any error, but object is not deleted from list in my Profile.

I have also tried by adding something like this in repository:

```
@Query(value = "{ '_id' : { '$oid' : ?0}}", delete = true)
void deleteRunningStyleById(String runningStyleId);
```

But it is not deleting it.

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I have added:

```
@Query(value = "{'$pull': {'runningStyle':{'_id' : ?0 }}}", delete = true)
void deleteRunningStyleById(String runningStyleId);
```

But I am getting following error:

```
unknown top level operator: $pull. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.
```

Comment: Did you try [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents)?

Comment: I havent can you please give example?

Comment: Try to run this: `db.collection.updateMany({}, {$pull:{runningStyle:{"_id" : ObjectId("61c05616a8237a39811ec3c2")}}})`. If works, translate it to Spring-Data syntax

Comment: I tried to add it but I am receiving error. Please look at my question update

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

### Call [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents)

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
...

@Override
public void deletePlayingStyle(String playingStyleId) {
    Update update = new Update();
    // $pull
    update.pull("runningStyle", new Document("_id", new ObjectId(playingStyleId)));
    
    //UpdateResult { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : x, "modifiedCount" : y }
    //check if modifiedCount > 0 to make sure profile updated
    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), update, Profile.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is it possible to adjust it to code that I already have?

Comment: No, `@Query` is used for `.find` not for `.updateXXX`